# Combining optional trailing slash pageviews in Google Analytics API pageviews report

Tags: regex, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm currently using this regex to grab a pageviews report for a certain segment of my site:

```
ga:pagePath=~^/cr/[a-zA-Z_0-9-]*\/*$
```

This returns all the pages under /cr to one level so it'll find /cr/somename and not /cr/somename/photos. The first level (somename) is all I want.

In the pageviews report, it breaks down separate numbers for results with or without trailing slashes:

```
/cr/somename/ 12 
/cr/somename 4
/cr/othername 2
etc.
```

Is there anyway in the API to combine the results so that the report will give me a combined pageviews of 16 for /somename or will I have to handle this addition in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to ask the API to combine and return results. You'll have to handle this on your end.

Comment: I created a filter on the GA profile that combines the two, so now it is not a issue with the API.